# Как это убрать, помогите

Tags: windows-10

В общем как убрать эту не знаю как назвать. Раньше при регулировке громкости появлялся только столбец уровня громкости. Потом вдруг стала появляться и эта хрень тоже. Как сделать, что бы она не появлялась?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я разобрался. Этот баннер добавляют **браузеры**!

Как отключить в Firefox (проверил сам):

- Вводим **about:config**
- Находим настройку **media.hardwaremediakeys.enabled**
- Устанавливаем в **false**

Как отключить в Chrome (взял [отсюда](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/how-to-disableremove-the-volume-popup-banner/16175e58-0a65-4935-a6d1-a9cae640be26)):

- Go to chrome://flags/#hardware-media-key-handling
- Set Hardware Media Key Handling to Disabled
- Restart the browser to apply the changes

Answer (score -1):

Никак не убрать. Это стандартный интерфейс Windows 10.

Comment: Не верю. Уверен как то можно убрать

Comment: Если только откатиться к старой винде

Comment: @RegalivDerif Чем мешает то? ;)

Comment: Кажется, что висит целую вечность. И не люблю лишнее на экране.

Comment: @RegalivDerif снесите винду и ставьте линукс) там такого нет и плюсом можно всем друзьям хвастаться, что пользуешься линуксом))

Comment: У меня на другом ноуте Mint. Все друганы уже в курсе, пора ещё заводить,  а то уже рассказывать некому.