# Как оключить это окошко?

Tags: windows, youtube

Когда смотрю ютуб с ноутбука часто появляетчя вот такое окно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оно очень сильно мешает, ведь из-за него часть экрана не видна. Как его отключить или хотя бы перенести в другое место?

Comment: Скорее всего это управление функциями мультимедиа Вашего ноутбука HP. Посмотрите на панели задач возле часов запущенные утилиты и попытайтесь через их настройки изменить поведение. Скорее всего эта утилита установилась автоматически как родная для ноутбука.

Comment: Скрыть можно щелчком по картинке в окошке.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1242585/184217

Answer (score 1):

Откройте браузер.

Шаг 1:
Введите в адресную строку
`chrome://flags/` или сразу же `chrome://flags/#hardware-media-key-handling`

Шаг 2:
В поиск введите (или сразу же найдите, прокрутив, подсвеченный пункт меню, если использовали второй вариант прямой ссылки) `Hardware Media Key Handling` и смените значение с `Default` на `Disabled`

Шаг 3:
Перезапустите браузер.